# How to get coverage report for Python enum entries?

Tags: python, test-coverage

Is it possible to check whether all of the values of an `Enum` have been used? For example, given the following code:

```py
from enum import Enum


class Prefix(Enum):
    FORMAL = "Hello"
    INFORMAL = "Hi"


def hello(name):
    return f"{Prefix.FORMAL.value}, {name}!"


def test_hello_with_sample_name() -> None:
    assert hello("Alice") == "Hello, Alice!"
```

Is it possible to configure Python's `coverage` module (or some other test runner) to report that line 6, `INFORMAL = "Hi"`, is unused?